# Hapi.js UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: reply interface called twice?

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

when I running my project, I get the error:

```
(node:5795) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: reply interface called twice
    at Object.exports.assert (/Users/labikemmy/Downloads/React-Native-FriendChat/api/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:736:11)
    at Function.internals.response (/Users/labikemmy/Downloads/React-Native-FriendChat/api/node_modules/hapi/lib/reply.js:164:10)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at Function.runBound (domain.js:314:12)
    at reply (/Users/labikemmy/Downloads/React-Native-FriendChat/api/node_modules/hapi/lib/reply.js:72:22)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:314:12)
    at result.then (/Users/labikemmy/Downloads/React-Native-FriendChat/api/node_modules/hapi/lib/handler.js:105:36)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
(node:5795) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5795) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
null
```

I don't know it is bug or my code error? I'm screen hapi.js issues, and someone said the error is bug, another said 'reply() times is limit in same request'? if it is limited, how to change the code at below?

```

```
export default async function (request, reply) {
    if (request.auth.credentials.email !== request.payload.email) {
        await User.findOne({ email: request.auth.credentials.email }).then(
            (user) => {
                if (user) {
                    User.findOne({ email: request.payload.email }).then(
                        (friend) => {
                            if (friend) {
                                const stringId = `${friend._id}`;
                                const friendExists = user.friends.filter(f => `${f}` === stringId).length > 0;
                                if (!friendExists) {
                                    user.friends.push(friend);
                                    user.save();
                                    reply({ friend: { fullName: friend.fullName, _id: friend._id } });
                                } else {
                                    reply(Boom.conflict('You have added already this friend'));
                                }
                             } else {
                                 reply(Boom.notFound(`Friend ${request.payload.email} doesn't exist`));
                             }
                        },
                   );
              } else {
                   reply(Boom.notFound('Cannot find user'));
              }
         },
     );
  } else {
      reply(Boom.conflict('Cannot add yourself as a friend'));
  }
}
```

Hapi@16.4.1

Comment: Unrelated to your query: your code needs some cleanup as it's unnecessarily complicated. Example: await promise.then is ambiguous. const variable = await.promise OR promise.then(variable=>{ ... }). To flatten out your nested ifs and increase readability, you can use a switch(true) with conditions or just use singular ifs that look for errors and throw. Also, if you throw an error from your handler then hapi will automatically reply it, so instead of using reply throughout, try using throw Boom.notFound(...). Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/hoaobrook/qd43txzp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any other plugins or lifecycle hooks like onPreHandler or something? Maybe there is some point your code that throws this error because you (or your code somehow) are calling reply interface before your actual response.

Also, I refactored your code. You are already utilizing JavaScript async interface, so you don't need to put "then" calls to your promises.

Try this and watch that what will come out:

```
export default async function (request, reply) {

    if (request.auth.credentials.email === request.payload.email) {
        return reply(Boom.conflict('Cannot add yourself as a friend'))
    }

    // I belive this is mongoose model
    const user = await User.findOne({email: request.auth.credentials.email}).exec();
    if (!user) {
        return reply(Boom.notFound('Cannot find user'));
    }

    const friend = await User.findOne({email: request.payload.email}).exec();

    if (!friend) {
        return reply(Boom.notFound(`Friend ${request.payload.email} doesn't exist`));
    }

    const stringId = `${friend._id}`;
    const friendExists = user.friends.filter(f => `${f}` === stringId).length > 0;
    if (!friendExists) {
        // hmmm shouldn't it be friend._id? user.friends.push(friend._id.toString());
        user.friends.push(friend);
        // better use this statement
        // ref: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified
        user.markModified('friends');
        await user.save();
        return reply({friend: {fullName: friend.fullName, _id: friend._id}});
    } else {
        return reply(Boom.conflict('You have added already this friend'));
    }
}
```